# export command not working in Jenkins groovy

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy

```
 export vara=$(grep '<Pattern>' $some_path/config/...../coreapplication_obips1/instanceconfig.xml | awk -F \> '{print $3}' | awk -F \< '{print $1}')
```

I am trying the above code in Jenkins pipeline using groovy script. It throws below error:

```
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310
```

How to execute shell script inside Jenkins groovy?

Comment: It's a shell script and you have to run it as external process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer the below to run shell and capture the output to a variable inside a Jenkins groovy file:-

```java
vara = sh (script: 'shell script need to be executed', returnStdout: true)
```

You can try something like this:-

```java
      steps {
         script {
                vara = sh (script: '''shell command''', returnStdout: true)
                echo " The value of variable id ${vara}"
                }
       }
```

Comment: The error is near "awk -F \". Above lines didn't help

Comment: Edited the answer, you have manipulate your script lit bit to make it work.

Comment: script: ''' grep '<Pattern>' $some_path/config/...../coreapplication_obips1/instanceconfig.xml | awk -F \> '{print $3}' | awk -F \< '{print $1}' '''

Comment: try with the above comment

Comment: WorkflowScript: 103: unexpected char: '\' @ line 103, column 218.
   1/instanceconfig.xml | awk -F \> '{print

Comment: you have to make some modifications from your side (this is the best way to capture shell output)

Comment: ok...I tried that, m getting a new error  now : Expected a step @ line 103, column 10 (near returnStdout: true == 0)

Comment: surround the code in steps blocks (please see updated answer)

Comment: err... the Jenkins job showed successful but when I checked the logs, it turned out that it's not able to put the script output in the variable!! Is there any other workaround?

Comment: Running shell script
2+ awk -F /
3+ awk -F /
4+ 1> {print $3}
5ath> /....../config/OracleBIPresentationServicesComponent/coreapplication_obips1/instanceconfig.xml
6+ A file or directory in the path name does not exist.

7 /path to Jenkins workspace/Pipelines/name of pipeline /script.sh[2]: {print $1}: 0403-016 Cannot find or open the file.

Comment: check if "instanceconfig.xml" file is present in that location

Comment: .......<Pattern>/......./coreapplication_obips1/catalog/SampleAppLite</Pattern>....... I want to put the line between <Pattern> and </Pattern> in a variable excluding the patterns. If this is done, the above problem will be solved. How is this possible to do?

Comment: from where you getting this "<Pattern>/......./coreapplication_obips1/catalog/SampleAppLite</Pattern>"?

Comment: It's in "instanceconfig.xml"